How to get the table by name in GAS?
I see that the concept of table was introduced in Google Sheets so I want to get that data in google app script:

Is there any method that can get the range or elements like: sheet.getTableByName("Table1") or sheet.getTables()?
I have reviewed and tested the methods provided in the documentation, and for example I can get the range object from the namedRanges but not from the Table object.
This post indicates that there is no method available until July 2024:

If you are specifically asking about tables created with Format >
Convert to table, there are currently (July 2024) no methods in the
SpreadsheetApp API that let you access table-specific attributes.
Specifically, there is no support to get a table by its name.

This question is pending until the functionality is implemented or there is some trick.

There are currently (September 2024) no methods in the SpreadsheetApp API that let you access tables. You will have to refer to the data through conventional means such as A1 notation, like this:
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getRange('A1:D5').getValues();

Assuming there's no unrelated data under the table, you can use an open-ended A1 type range reference like A1:D and filter out blank rows, like this:
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const data = sheet.getRange('A1:D').getValues().filter(row => row.join('');

You can also use other types of criteria Array.filter() to grab the correct rows based on labels and such things.
Another alternative is to use a named range that covers all of the table plus a few additional rows, like this:
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const data = ss.getRange('NamedRange1').getValues().filter(row => row.join('');

When you Insert > Rows within the table (or below it, but still within the named range), the snippet above will continue to return all of the data.

Unfortunately it doesn't work because the range of a table is dynamic, and instead the methods you indicate are only for static ranges. I tried to use named range but when I add more rows to the table it doesn't change.

Comments are used to indicate why the answer is chosen or not, and the drawbacks that the possible solutions may have. In your solution, for example, I can have several tables (obviously with different names) occupying the same columns, so I cannot obtain the data. Thank you for trying to help me.

Please add all relevant details directly in the question, or in the event there already are answers that would be invalidated by the new info, preferably post a new question that specifies those details.

I like your workaround, using the first row of the table as a reference.

As of September 2024 there are no methods to handle Google Sheets tables using Google Apps Script.
We should wait until a release note announce that new methods has been added.
